# Continuous Deployment Using Travis CI and Docker

Tags: docker, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

What is the best way to automate the deployment of a Docker image in a CI environment?

After building a simple web project using Travis CI and using a `Dockerfile` to build the corresponding Docker image, is there a way to automatically cause that image to be deployed to a cloud provider?

Right now, the Dockerfile pulls down the base image to the Travis build machine and builds the image based on the instructions in the Dockerfile. At this point if the build is successful I can push it to the Docker Hub, though I have no need save this image to the Docker hub, what I envision is deploying the successfully built Docker image to a cloud provider (IE. DigitalOcean, Linode, or AWS) and starting/running the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While pushing directly to a host might seem ideal, I think it ignores the fact that hosts can fail, or may need to be replicated.

If you push directly to a prod host, and that host goes down, you don't have any way to start another one without re-running the entire CI pipeline.

If you push to an intermediary (the hub or a docker registry), you can create as many hosts as you want without having to re-run the build. You can also recover on a new host very easily (the initialize script can just pull the image and start).

If you wanted to, you could run your own registry on the cloud provider (instead of using the hub).

Comment: okay, so I push the image to a docker registry, at this step what is the best approach to automating the install of the newly created and pushed docker image? The end state is continuous deployment with the newly created docker image.

Comment: Ah ya, I don't really have a good answer to that part of the question.  I think you'd probably want a crontab somewhere to pull, and restart containers when they change.  I don't know of any tools that fit that piece.

Answer (score 1):

For a static website, you might want to look at [Surge](https://surge.sh).

Otherwise, you might want to look at the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (AWS EB CLI) in combination with using docker with AWS EB.

For using docker with AWS EB, read this [AWS Blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1ZLAHMVBEDCOC/Dockerizing-a-Python-Web-App)

For AWS EB CLI, here is an excerpt from the AWS EB dashboard sidebar

> If you want to use a command line to create, manage, and scale your
>   Elastic Beanstalk applications, please use the Elastic Beanstalk
>   Command Line Interface (EB CLI). Get Started
>
> ```
> $ mkdir HelloWorld
> $ cd HelloWorld
> $ eb init -p PHP
> $ echo "Hello World" > index.html
> $ eb create dev-env
> $ eb open
> ```
>
> To deploy updates to your applications, use ‘eb deploy’.

Further reading

- [Installing the AWS EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/elasticbeanstalk/eb-cli-install)
- [EB CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/elasticbeanstalk/eb-cli-commands)

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same question.

There's a very cool docker image called [Watchtower](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower) that checks the running version of a container with the same image tag on Docker hub. If there is an update on the hub, Watchtower pulls the newer image and restarts the running container (retaining all the env vars etc). Works really well for single containers that need updating.

NB: it really is as simple as running:

```
docker run -d \
--name watchtower \
-e REPO_USER="username" -e REPO_PASS="pass" -e REPO_EMAIL="email" \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
drud/watchtower container_to_watch --debug
```

I'm looking for the same thing but for the containers running as part of a docker swarm...